# Monitor CAN/Flexray messages on the bus CAPL

Tags: capl, canoe

I'm trying to learn CAPL and Im trying to accomplish the following .
I have a huge matrix of communication with strict timing.
Id like to have a CAPL code which can monitor all the messages if the were received or not , check there periodicity.
I'm able to read the Write CSV files in and from CAPL and thats how i'm getting my input and transmitting the output.

The point here. does CAPL supports providing insights or statistics about a message like (Max peroid , avg Peroid , Min Peroid) , was it transmitted or not.how to obtian such info from CAPL

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code by editing it into your question.

Comment: Well i don't know how to access the messages statistics. i can subscribe to a message on event and do the calculation but thats not practical since , Canoe already has all these information on its trace window. but how to access it thats my question

Answer (score 0):

CAPL primitive functions provide you **TestCheck** functions, which have a multitude of versions (check relative cycle time, Absolute Cycle time, Occurence etc.) for checking in a parallel thread something specific about your messages (like cycle time).

**ChkCreate_MsgAbsCycleTimeViolation()** is one example.

They provide you a test result with detailed tables of minimum-maximum cycle times, distribution on a cycle time scale and so on.

Search TestCheck functions up in the CANoe help for description and examples.